# Why does inflating an Android layout take so long?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have a dialog in Android. There is a noticeable lag when it opens. Here is what I did to investigate:

1. Using crude timing with System.currentTime, my onCreateDialog method takes 150ms on a good day on 500-700ms on a regular day.
2. I implemented my own LayoutInflator.Factory. My factory doesn't do anything. It simply returns null to let the default factory do the work. Yet it writes out the elapsed time since the last call. That way, I get a printout of how long each tag in the layout xml takes to inflate. Very surprisingly, each element takes about 20-70ms to inflate!
3. I profiled the app. It appears that a lot of the time is indeed spent in the constructor of views or the LayoutParams.
4. For a crude check, I measured the time to call the constructor on TextView with System.currentTime. It turns out in my emulator on a strong Alienware PC, it takes 20-70ms to instantiate a TextView object! Something seems to be amiss that it could take so long.

For reference, there is a difference between layout inflation, measuring, and rendering. I'm only concerned with the performance for inflation right now.

Here is how I implemented the LayoutInflator.Factory to take my measurements:

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater2 = inflater.cloneInContext(getActivity());
    inflater2.setFactory(new LayoutInflater.Factory() {

        long inner = System.currentTimeMillis();

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateView: Called factory for " + name + " took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - inner));
            inner = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Here is the output:

```
Called factory for TextView took 34
Called factory for TextView took 30
Called factory for android.support.constraint.Guideline took 76
...
```

Here is how I measured the time for instatiating a TextView and LayoutParams object.

```
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateDialog: 10 " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - last));  last = System.currentTimeMillis();

    new TextView(getActivity());
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateDialog: 11 " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - last));  last = System.currentTimeMillis();

    new ConstraintLayout(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateDialog: 12 " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - last));  last = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Here is my layout, but all layouts in the app seem to be affected by the slowness:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/remote_message_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/remote_dialog_message"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/building_name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/remote_message_text_view"
        tools:text="Bakery"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/building_icon_image_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/building_icon_content_description"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/right_guide_line"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/left_guide_line"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/building_name_text_view"
        tools:src="@drawable/bakery"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_heading_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/actions_heading"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/building_icon_image_view"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_grid_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/action_heading_text_view"
        tools:layout_height="100dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/production_rules_heading_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/production_rules_heading"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/action_grid_layout"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/production_rules_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/production_rules_heading_text_view"
        tools:text="1 flour creates 1 bread."/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/production_speed_heading_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/production_speed_heading"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/production_rules_text_view"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/production_speed_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/production_speed_heading_text_view"
        tools:text="1 peasant produces 1 unit per 60 minutes.\n(Add a peasant to cut the time to 30 minutes.)"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countdown_heading_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/next_unit_count_down_heading"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/production_speed_text_view"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countdown_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/countdown_heading_text_view"
        tools:text="24 : 60 : 60"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/left_guide_line"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".33"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/right_guide_line"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".66"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Why is inflating the layout so slow. How can I speed it up?

Comment: "I measured the time to call the constructor on TextView with System.currentTime. It turns out in my emulator on a strong Alienware PC, it takes 20-70ms to instantiate a TextView object!" -- I cannot reproduce your results. The *first* `TextView` may take a bit, as some things may be lazy-initialized. The second and subsequent ones are fast (sub-millisecond), on emulators and hardware. Note that I used `nanoTime()` for timing. Perhaps there are issues with your development machine or emulator.

Comment: When I repeat the measurements on a Pixel device, each step in the LayoutInflator takes 5-8ms. The total layout inflation is still 102ms, which seems like a lot for a simple layout. Inflating TextView and LayoutParams takes about 3-8ms. I agree that these things should take sub ms, a whole layout perhaps 0-10ms. Something strange is going on. I've restarted the emulator without change.

Comment: Make sure that you have Instant Run disabled, as there is a chance that it is interfering with your performance analysis.

Comment: Disabling instant run was a good tip. It's faster, but inflating the layout still takes over 100ms.

Answer (score -1):

Creating the views is only a small subset of the work LayoutInflater does.  You aren't initializing them, you aren't adding them to their parents, you aren't setting properties on them, you aren't creating LayoutParams, you aren't doing a layout or measure pass.  You aren't even parsing xml.  When you do 10% of the work it takes 10% of the time.   Your comparison is totally useless.

Comment: When I measured with the Android Studio profiler, most of the time was spent in the view constructor and LayoutParams constructor, not 10% of the time. Also simply calling the constructor on TextView or LayoutParams took roughly as many milliseconds as the LayoutInflator took to handle one view (see my experiment with the Factory).

Comment: You're using the 1 param constructor. The inflated parses the props and uses the 3. Even your constructor is doing 10 percent of the work